# ¿ Por qué no se ejecuta el UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysql, angular

Buen día comunidad, estoy haciendo una WebApp con Angular 8 y tengo un Backend con PHP y MySQL, me surge el siguiente inconveniente.
El backend con php no ejecuta la sentencia `UPDATE` de MySQL, adjunto mi codigo.

```
Service**
update = `http://192.168.1.123/codigos/consultas/serverUp.php?mat=`;

updateImp( m ){

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }),
  observe: 'response' as 'body'
};
return this.http.put(`${this.update}`, m, httpOptions );
}
```

Componente:

```
imprimir( data ){
   let i = this.data[0][0].impresion;

if ( i == '0') {
  this.mysql.updateImp(m);
}else {
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Error!',
    text: 'Ya has impreso tus boletos con anterioridad.',
    icon: 'error'
  });
}
}
```

Backend:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, 
Accept");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
$mat = $_GET['mat'];

if ($mat ===  ' ') {
  echo "<script> console.log('campo vacio');</script>";
}else {
  $sql = "UPDATE graduaciones SET impresion = 1 where matricula= '$mat'";
  echo $sql; 
}
```

Lo que pasa aquí es que el `query` no se ejecuta, pero tampoco me muestra error alguno, ¿ Alguien me puede ayudar ??

Comment: Esta línea `$mat ===  ' '` no esta validando un campo vacío pues entre las comillas hay un espacio en blanco, primer punto quita ese espacio quedando asi: `$mat ===  ''`

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "UPDATE graduaciones SET impresion = 1
             where matricula='".$mat."'";
```

Podría estar la sentencia mal escrita prueba así a ver que tal. Y también comprueba el flujo para ver si se entra bien por el flujo del if y del else.